# NavBar Not Changing In React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the NavBar to switch in React based on if a user is signed in or not and also to display the users name in the navbar when signed in. I have two components called NavBar (when not signed in) and UserNav (when signed in). For whatever reason the nav isn't switching when the user is signed in. When using the React DevTools it still shows NavBar component when user is signed in. Display name isn't showing up either. Here is the code.

App.js

```
var React = require('react');
var NavBar = require('./components/NavBar/NavBar');
var UserNav = require('./components/UserNav/UserNav');

// Main App
// <App />
var App = React.createClass({
  handleSignIn : function(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the     Google API.
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
    });
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log(user);
  },
  render : function() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log(user);
    return (
      <div className="digestible-app">
       {user ? <UserNav handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn}/> : <NavBar handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn} />}
        <main>
           {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </div>
     );
   }
 });
```

UserNav.js

```
var React = require('react');
var App = require('../../App');

// UserNav
// <UserNav />
var UserNav = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button className="createQuizBtn btn btn-default navbar-btn" style={{ marginRight : 20 }}>Create a Quiz</button></li>
            <li><button className="display-name btn btn-default navbar-btn" onClick={this.props.handleSignIn}>{user.displayName}</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav> 
    );
  }
});

module.exports = UserNav;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are keeping your user as a standalone variable instead of having it as a part of your state. React will only rerender your components when state is changed. So instead of having a variable for your user you should make it part of you state and set it when the user logs in (or logs out).

```
// code code code ...
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
  return {user: null};
},
handleSignIn : function(){
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the     Google API.
  var token = result.credential.accessToken
  // The signed-in user info. Put this into state to force a rerender.
  setState({user: result.user});
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
});
// I don't think you need this code, but if so you should be setting 
// the user to state, same as above.
// var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
// console.log(user);
},
render : function() {
  // get the user from state.
  const user = this.state.user;
  console.log(user);
  return (
    // the same logic you had for rendering.
    // ...
```

Related side note, when you get the current user using auth.currentUser at app initialization you may get null. If you run into issues where remember me isn't working you should look at using [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) to get the user. More info and an [example here](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/firebase-auth-v3-with-react-native.html#remember-me).

Comment: Ahhh. Ok, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! I'll test it out soon.